# react-router why does code continue executing after the transition?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using react-router and have a function to programmatically go to another page:

```
  transitionTo(url) {
    hashHistory.push(url)
  }
```

It works fine, but I'm puzzled because if there is more code after the transition, then the code will continue to run.  I would have expected execution to finish after the transition.

i.e. the following code will transition through each of the specified routes, ending up on /flib

```
transitionTo('/floob')
transitionTo('/flub')
transitionTo('/flib')
```

Why is this?

I would have expected it transitions straight to /floob and does not get to /flub or /flib

Comment: I would imagine it's because the change detection is debounced to some degree, so only the last item goes through.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing that stops next line of code from execution.

First of all `transitionTo()` is just a normal function call. Why would it prevent next line from execution unless it throws an exception?

If you were expecting that history transition causes some sort of page reloading. It does not. Neither `HistoryAPI` nor plain old `hashchange` (as in your case) does this. Nor it would be an expected behaviour. Since you do want to keep the context you were in.

And even if you stick to `location` api that actully changes browsing context it wouldn't prevent next line from execution.

```
console.log('before');
window.location.assign('https://google.com')
window.location.assign('https://stackoverflow.com')
window.location.assign('https://example.com')
console.log('after');
```

Comment: "Why would it prevent next line from execution unless it throws an exception?" I guess I thought the target page would start executing.

Comment: @DukeDougal I see. As I said there is no page reloading. But even if it were current call stack would be executed. And even more. There is `beforeunload` event that potentially could prevent page reloading.